# Is there a way to accept payments once a sales target is reached?

Tags: paypal

My client wants to be able to sell 20 items before any money is transferred through PayPal. Is there a way to queue up payments in this way, and then 'release' them once a goal is met using the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Authorize and capture model.[API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/)

`Authorization & Capture is for merchants who have a delayed order fulfillment process and who typically make a $1 USD authorization at checkout. It enables merchants to modify the original authorization amount due to order changes (such as taxes, shipping, or item availability) that occur after the buyers place the initial order. This chapter discusses the authorization and capture process and provides steps to help you authorize, capture, reauthorize, and void funds.`